# IBM Worklight - What does a striked-through line means?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

Can anyone explain why when I have typed some code lines, they appear with a line through it? For example when using `WL.Page.load` or `WL.Page.back`.

Comment: What? Add a link to a screen shot...

Comment: Sounds like something is deprecated if a line is going through it. But like said we need a screenshot

Comment: It says you need 10 reputation points to post it.

Comment: this is the text if it helps...              WL.Page.load("Page1.html", {
  onComplete: function(){ PAGE1INS.init(); },
  onUnload: function() {PAGE1INS.unload();}
 });
 break;
case 2:
 WL.Page.load("Page2.html", {
  onComplete:function(){ PAGE2NS.init(); },
  onUnload: function() { PAGE2NS.unload(); }
 });
 break

Comment: Open another question please; this one is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WL.Page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_page_load.html), part of the Fragments and Pages feature in Worklight, is a **deprecated** feature (meaning one that may/will be removed in a future release).

I believe from your description that the strike-through denotes the deprecation in the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: ok thanks, so even though I am getting this it shouldnt really be the reason why its not working.

Comment: If it is not working, something else is not working. :) The API is still operable.